# How to add tag field in django?

Tags: python, django

Here I have some model and this model should have some tags for making it SEO friendly.For this how can i design my model?

Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.

my model

```
class TourPackage(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    package_detail = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField()
    booking_start = models.DateTimeField()
    booking_end= = models.DateTimeField()
    package_start = models.DateTimeField()
    #how  can i save this tag field for seo purpose
    #tag = models.CharField()
```

Comment: SEO friendly has nothing to do with your model. `CharField` will work okay. You need to create your web page/API such that crawlers can query data.

Comment: SEO don't involve your database, it's about your front end and how your api is organized

Comment: @HelloWorld: the database is of no importance. search engines have no access to the database at all (well let's hope so). You thus will need to *render* `<meta>` tags, etc in the pages.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem if so can i just use `CharField` for the tags field in my model

Comment: @HelloWorld: you can, although that might not be ideal, since for example searching by tag would make it harder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I advice to make use of a package, like for example [**`django-taggit`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/jazzband/django-taggit), this implements a many-to-many field, but with some extra tooling to make managing tags more convenient.

You can install the package, for example with the pip package manager in your virtual environment:

```
pip install django-taggit
```

In your `settings.py`, you then add `'taggit'` to the `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```
# settings.py

# …

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # …,
    'taggit',
    # …,
]
```

Then you can add a `TaggableManager` to your model:

```
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

class TourPackage(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    package_detail = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField()
    booking_start = models.DateTimeField()
    booking_end = models.DateTimeField()
    package_start = models.DateTimeField()

    tag = TaggableManager()
```

Of course this will *not* add the tags to the page. You will need to write `<meta>` tags in your templates to add meta information.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you correct, you can use Many-To-Many relationship according to the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/). 
But it implies that each TourPackage model may have many tags against only one as in your example.

You should use something like this

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)             

class TourPackage(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    package_detail = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField()
    booking_start = models.DateTimeField()
    booking_end= = models.DateTimeField()
    package_start = models.DateTimeField()
    #how  can i save this tag field for seo purpose
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag')
```

And then

```
tp = TourPackage(...)
tag1 = Tag.objects.create(name='tag1')
tag2 = Tag.objects.create(name='tag2')
tp.tags.add(tag1)
tp.tags.add(tag1)
tp.save()
```